# Some fields in a Formik form are not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a special `TextField` wrapper for a Material-UI field that seems to be working well. For some reason when I use native Material UI fields, they do not update the form data upon submission.

Here is the relevant code (but I've added a code sandbox at the end of the post to help demonstrate the issue)

**TestForm.tsx**

```js
import { Card, CardActions, CardContent } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Form, Formik, Field } from "formik";
import React from "react";
import SubmitButton from "../../SubmitButton";
import CancelButton from "../../CancelButton";
import TextField from "../../TextField";
import MuiTextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

interface TestFormProps {
  onSave: (fields: FormFields) => void;
  onCancel: () => void;
}

export interface FormFields {
  textField: string;
  numericField: number;
  materialField: string;
  materialFieldFromComponent: string;
}

const initialValues: FormFields = {
  textField: "Default Text",
  numericField: 42,
  materialField: "Default Mui",
  materialFieldFromComponent: "Default Mui from Component"
};

const TestForm: React.FC<TestFormProps> = ({ onCancel, onSave }) => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onSubmit={async (fields, { setSubmitting }) => {
        setSubmitting(true);
        onSave(fields);
      }}
    >
      {({ isSubmitting }) => (
        <Form>
          <Card>
            <CardContent>
              <TextField name="textField" label="Text field" />
              <TextField
                name="numericField"
                type="number"
                label="Numeric field"
              />
              <div>
                <MuiTextField
                  name="materialField"
                  label="Mui field"
                  variant="outlined"
                  margin="dense"
                />
              </div>
              <Field
                name="materialFieldFromComponent"
                label="Mui field from Component"
                variant="outlined"
                margin="dense"
                component={MuiTextField}
              />
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
              <SubmitButton disabled={isSubmitting} />
              <CancelButton onCancel={onCancel} />
            </CardActions>
          </Card>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default TestForm;
```

**TextField.tsx**

```js
import React from "react";
import { FieldAttributes, useField } from "formik";
import {
  InputBaseComponentProps,
  TextField as MuiTextField
} from "@material-ui/core";

interface TextFieldProps {
  label: string;
  inline?: boolean;
  inputProps?: InputBaseComponentProps;
}

const Field: React.FC<FieldAttributes<TextFieldProps>> = (props) => {
  const { type, label, placeholder, inputProps } = props;
  const [field, meta] = useField<TextFieldProps>(props);
  const errorText = meta.error && meta.touched ? meta.error : "";

  return (
    <MuiTextField
      {...field}
      label={label}
      variant="outlined"
      margin="dense"
      type={type}
      placeholder={placeholder ? placeholder : label}
      helperText={errorText}
      error={!!errorText}
      inputProps={inputProps}
    />
  );
};

const TextField: React.FC<FieldAttributes<TextFieldProps>> = ({
  inline = false,
  ...props
}) => {
  return inline ? (
    <Field {...props} />
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Field {...props} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextField;
```

Here's the code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-northcutt-5deen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `TextField` that you have created passes the correct field properties, while the other direct implementation of the material UI fields do not.

Passing the correct properties as follow, will do the trick:

```
    {({ isSubmitting, handleChange, handleBlur, values }) => (
              ...
              <div>
                <MuiTextField
                  name="materialField"
                  label="Mui field"
                  variant="outlined"
                  margin="dense"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  value={values.materialField}
                />
              </div>
              <Field
                name="materialFieldFromComponent"
                label="Mui field from Component"
                variant="outlined"
                margin="dense"
                render={({ field }) => <MuiTextField {...field} />}
              />
         ...
```

The `MuiTextField` now has `onChange` and `values` passed on its properties, thus updating the values correctly.

Complete code: **TestForm.tsx**

```
import { Card, CardActions, CardContent } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Form, Formik, Field } from "formik";
import React from "react";
import SubmitButton from "../../SubmitButton";
import CancelButton from "../../CancelButton";
import TextField from "../../TextField";
import MuiTextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

interface TestFormProps {
  onSave: (fields: FormFields) => void;
  onCancel: () => void;
}

export interface FormFields {
  textField: string;
  numericField: number;
  materialField: string;
  materialFieldFromComponent: string;
}

const initialValues: FormFields = {
  textField: "Default Text",
  numericField: 42,
  materialField: "Default Mui",
  materialFieldFromComponent: "Default Mui from Component"
};

const TestForm: React.FC<TestFormProps> = ({ onCancel, onSave }) => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onSubmit={async (fields, { setSubmitting }) => {
        setSubmitting(true);
        onSave(fields);
      }}
    >
      {({ isSubmitting, handleChange, handleBlur, values }) => (
        <Form>
          <Card>
            <CardContent>
              <TextField name="textField" label="Text field" />
              <TextField
                name="numericField"
                type="number"
                label="Numeric field"
              />
              <div>
                <MuiTextField
                  name="materialField"
                  label="Mui field"
                  variant="outlined"
                  margin="dense"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  value={values.materialField}
                />
              </div>
              <Field
                name="materialFieldFromComponent"
                label="Mui field from Component"
                variant="outlined"
                margin="dense"
                render={({ field }) => <MuiTextField {...field} />}
              />
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
              <SubmitButton disabled={isSubmitting} />
              <CancelButton onCancel={onCancel} />
            </CardActions>
          </Card>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default TestForm;
```